# Can I get a this variable in a def?

Tags: clojure

Is there a way to mimic a `this` variable in something like `(def foo {:two 2 :three (inc (:two this))})`? Even better would be something like `(def foo {:two 2 :three (inc ::two)})`. I was told that there is a library that does exactly this, but I can't really find anything similar.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Update:* Rearranged & reworked. `build-map` and (a sketch of) `-m>` macros added.)

You could write this particular example as

```
(def foo (zipmap [:two :three] (iterate inc 2)))
```

The easiest general solution which occurs to me at this moment is

```
user> (-> {} (assoc :two 2) (#(assoc % :three (inc (:two %)))))
{:three 3, :two 2}
```

It's actually very flexible, although it does require you to write out `assoc` repeatedly.

To enable syntax similar to that from the question text, you could use something like this:

```
(defn build-map* [& kvs]
  (reduce (fn [m [k v]]
            (assoc m k (v m)))
          {}
          kvs))

(defmacro build-map [& raw-kvs]
  (assert (even? (count raw-kvs)))
  (let [kvs (map (fn [[k v]] [k `(fn [m#] (let [~'this m#] ~v))])
                 (partition 2 raw-kvs))]
    `(build-map* ~@kvs)))

user> (build-map :two 2 :three (inc (:two this)))
{:three 3, :two 2}
```

You could easily change this to use a user-supplied symbol rather than the hardcoded `this`. Or you could switch to `%`, which is just a regular symbol outside anonymous function literals. Maybe add an explicit initial map argument, call it `-m>` (for map threading) and you can do

```
(-m> {} :two 2 :three (inc (:two %)))
```

for the same result.

---

Another funky way (mostly for the fun):

```
;;; from Alex Osborne's debug-repl,
;;; see http://gist.github.com/252421
;;; now changed to use &env
(defmacro local-bindings
  "Produces a map of the names of local bindings to their values."
  []
  (let [symbols (map key &env)]
    (zipmap (map (fn [sym] `(quote ~sym)) symbols) symbols)))

(let [two 2
      three (inc two)]
  (into {} (map (fn [[k v]] [(keyword k) v]) (local-bindings))))
{:two 2, :three 3}
```

Note that this will also capture the bindings introduced by any outer let forms...

Answer (score 4):

If you want a temporary name for something, that's what `let` is for.

```
(def foo (let [x {:two 2}]
           (assoc x :three (inc (:two x)))))
```

I don't know of any library that does what you want.  Every once in a while, someone suggests a "generalized arrow", like `->` but with a magic symbol you can stick in the intermediary expressions which will be replaced by something else.  See for example [here](http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/browse_thread/thread/2cc0f1f1abe6e1de/ec4298c1d681d457) and [here](http://groups.google.com/group/clojure-dev/msg/89a63aaf214d6438).  But this idea tends to be shot down because it's more complex and confusing for little benefit.  `let` is your friend.  See Rich's example:

```
(let [x []
      x (conj x 1)
      x (into x [2 3])
      x (map inc x)]
...)
```

Comment: +1 for existing solution over new complex magic constructions.